# WLAN state UP by systemd service, but does not work after authorization as a user

Tags: debian, systemd, wlan

I have a Debian buster. My task is to turn on Wi-Fi and connect to the access point right before authorization. For this, I want to use a `systemd` service. I wrote a script:

```
/usr/sbin/ip link set wlo1 up
/usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i wlo1 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
/usr/sbin/dhclient wlo1
```

When I run it from the `systemd` service, it says that the script worked successfully. But after authorization as a user, the WLAN state is DOWN. So `ip a show wlo1` says. And therefore, for example, `ping 8.8.8.8` says `connect: Network is unreachable`.

My script works for sure because if I run it manually as a user with superuser rights, I will successfully set WLAN state UP and connect to the access point.

My systemd service:

```
[Unit]
BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlo1.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlo1.device
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/my_script.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I will clarify. My `systemd` service starts at system startup as expected. `systemctl status` says that the service completed all the commands in the `ExecStart` field and finished work successfully. I don't want to know how to solve my problem in another way. I want to understand why this method does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The default is `KillMode=control-group`, so systemd kills off your `wpa_supplicant` process when your script exits, as prescribed for *oneshot* type units entering inactive state.